# Exporting data containing line feeds as CSV from PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv, view, export

I'm trying to export data From postgresql to csv.

First i created the query and tried exporting From pgadmin with the File -> Export to CSV. The CSV is wrong, as it contains for example :

The header : Field1;Field2;Field3;Field4

Now, the rows begin well, except for the last field that it puts it on another line:

Example :

Data1;Data2;Data3;

Data4;

The problem is i get error when trying to import the data to another server.

The data is From a view i created.

I also tried

```
COPY view(field1,field2...) TO 'C:\test.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

It exports the same file.

I just want to export the data to another server.

Edit:

When trying to import the csv i get the error :

> ERROR : Extra data after the last expected column. Context Copy
>   actions, line 3: <<"Data1, data2 etc.">>

[image]

So the first line is the header, the second line is the first row with data minus the last field, which is on the 3rd line, alone.

Comment: The csv that is exported has the last field in another line, which will give me error when trying to import it on another server.

Comment: please **quote** the command and exception you get

Comment: and please a line of generated csv where it stops )or better three lines (with surronding)

Comment: from the error I assume that you have less columns in a table to which you try to "import" data. please give us DDL of both tables (export one and import one)

Comment: @AlexE. In order to other users to find your question better, consider changing the title to something more explicit, e.g. "Exporting data containing line feeds as CSV from PostgreSQL to a remote server"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for you to export the file in another server you have two options:

- Creating a shared folder between the two servers, so that the
  database also has access to this directory.

`COPY (SELECT field1,field2 FROM your_table) TO '[shared directory]' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;`

- Triggering the export from the target server using the `STDOUT` of
  `COPY`. Using `psql` you can achieve this running the following
  command:

`psql yourdb -c "COPY (SELECT * FROM your_table) TO STDOUT" > output.csv`

**EDIT**: Addressing the issue of fields containing line feeds (`\n`)

In case you wanna get rid of the line feeds, use the `REPLACE` function.

Example:

```
 SELECT E'foo\nbar';
 ?column? 
----------
 foo     +
 bar
(1 Zeile)
```

Removing the line feed:

```
SELECT REPLACE(E'foo\nbaar',E'\n','');
 replace 
---------
 foobaar
(1 Zeile)
```

So your `COPY` should look like this:

```
COPY (SELECT field1,REPLACE(field2,E'\n','') AS field2 FROM your_table) TO '[shared directory]' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

Comment: Like i said in the op, i tried the Copy command, and while it works, the csv that it creates has the error of the last field being in a new line , which gives error when trying to import.

Comment: Can you edit your question showing the error message? Normally using quotes (perhaps even `FORCE QUOTE`?) would avoid error in case of fields containing line feeds.

Comment: Can you try something like this and let us know? `COPY (SELECT field1,field2)  TO '/tmp/copy_test.csv' WITH CSV FORCE QUOTE field2;` . Considering `field2` is the problematic one.

Comment: I just added 2 more fields to the query, and now i have a new line with the last 3 fields.

Comment: is it possible that your fields contain line feeds? I mean, even if they do, postgres should generate a valid csv file.

Comment: For some reason , after the 6th field, it changes line.

Comment: Intriguing. Although, it does not mean the csv file is invalid. According to the image you just uploaded, it seems right. I would argue that the field `codacc` contains a line feed (`\n`) in the end.

Comment: Ok, after changing the fields order, i found out that the field 'observaciones' indeed has a line feed (i did not know it was posible in SQL).

How could i fix this?

Comment: I got the following query
 'SELECT REPLACE(crm.vclientesaccage.observaciones,E'\n',''),REPLACE(crm.vclientesaccage.interlocutor,E'\n','') ,crm.vclientesaccage.codage,crm.vclientesaccage.codacc,crm.cclientesv.razon, crm.cclientesv.poblacion,crm.cclientesv.domicilio,crm.vclientesaccage.fecha,crm.vclientesaccage.codefe
from crm.cclientesv 
INNER JOIN crm.vclientesaccage
on crm.cclientesv.razon = crm.vclientesaccage.razon' 

I dont think the REPLACE Works as it names the fields "REPLACE".

Comment: of course it does work, you just have to use an alias. I'll edit the answer once again with the following change: `REPLACE(field2,E'\n','') AS field2`

Answer (score 0):

the described above export procedure is OK, e.g:

```
t=# create table so(i int, t text);
CREATE TABLE
t=# insert into so select 1,chr(10)||'aaa';
INSERT 0 1
t=# copy so to stdout csv header;
i,t
1,"
aaa"
t=# create table so1(i int, t text);
CREATE TABLE
t=# copy so1 from stdout csv header;
Enter data to be copied followed by a newline.
End with a backslash and a period on a line by itself, or an EOF signal.
>> i,t
1,"
aaa"
>> >> >> \.
COPY 1
t=# select * from so1;
 i |  t
---+-----
 1 |    +
   | aaa
(1 row)
```

Comment: Could you explain  what exactly would this do? This is too advanced for me.