# Export .csv file (with headers) from PostgreSQL table using PHP PDO, first data row missing

Tags: php, postgresql

sorry for the probably pretty easy question but I'm very new to PHP and SQL in general.

I'm trying to export a CSV file form a PostgreSQL table using PHP PDO. Everything is working fine a part from the missing first data row.

This is my code:

```
<?php

function bb()
{
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "postgres";
$password = "mypassword";
$dbname = "mydb";

$conn = new PDO("pgsql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM foundation"); 
$stmt->execute();

$filename = 'test_postgres.csv';

header('Content-type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename);
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: UTF-8");

$head = fopen($filename, 'w');

$headers = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
fputcsv($head, array_keys($headers));

fclose($head);

$data = fopen($filename, 'a');

    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        fputcsv($data, $row);
    }

fclose($data);
}

bb();

?>
```

This is what I should have:

[image: img1]

while this is what I can see:

[image]

I think I'm writing the headers in place of the first data row but I cannot find a way to avoid this issue. Any idea?

Thanks, Stefano.

Comment: Did you take a look at `COPY`? e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49486039/exporting-data-containing-line-feeds-as-csv-from-postgresql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when you read the row for the header, that is the first row of the data, so you need to write the data from here to the data file as well...

```
$headers = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
fputcsv($head, array_keys($headers));

fclose($head);

$data = fopen($filename, 'a');
fputcsv($data, $headers);  // This adds the data from the header row

    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        fputcsv($data, $row);
    }
```

Comment: Right. Also, I think there is no need to close the file and reopen it with `'a'`. no?

Comment: Unless there is a good reason to close the file, just open it once and write to it.

Comment: Great, perfectly working now, thanks. Just for curiosity, could you explain me what's the role of `array_keys($headers)` here, if then we have `fputcsv($data, $headers)`?

Comment: When you use `FETCH_ASSOC`, this means the data has the field names from the SQL (actually the column names in this case) as the key (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846531/how-to-read-fetchpdofetch-assoc/16858666), so `array_keys()` gives an array of the column names of all of the fields which forms your headers.